# Why is `B /. h -> #2 &` not a pure function?

Tags: plotting, pure-function, mesh

I am trying to plot the energy surface of the mean field Ising model,
but I am running into a problem with setting the `MeshFunctions` for the plot.

```
F = 2 d M + h
u = -F σ
z = Exp[-β u]
Z = Sum[z, {σ, {-1, 1}}] // FullSimplify
M0 = Sum[z σ, {σ, {-1, 1}}]/Z // FullSimplify

b = Solve[M0 == M &&  F/M <= 6 d && d >= 1, {β}, Reals][[1]] 

U = D[-Log[Z], β] // FullSimplify
c = D[Log[Z], {β, 2}] // FullSimplify
ρ = (-M + 1)/2 // FullSimplify
S = β U + Log[Z] // FullSimplify
T = 1/β // FullSimplify
A = -T Log[Z] // FullSimplify
Reduce[A == U - T S]

d = 2
pp[x_, y_, z_] := 
 ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, z} /. b /. M -> If[h < 0, -1, 1] * m, {m, 0, 
   1}, {h, -2^2, 2^2}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
  MeshFunctions -> (T /. b /. h -> #2 &)]

pp[h, T, A]
```

The surface plots, but I get the error

```
MeshFunctions::invmeshf: "MeshFunctions-> T /. b /. h->#2& must be a pure function or a list of pure functions"
```

and no mesh.

However, as @MrWizard's answer shows, `MeshFunctions -> (T /. h -> #2 &)` works in simpler examples.

Comment: Hm. It works in MMA 10.0.1. Which version of MMA are you using?

Comment: @OliverJennrich I have 10.0 Linux Home Edition

Comment: @OliverJennrich You are right. I tried to simplify the example for posting, but I oversimplified it. I put in the example that actually fails now.

Answer (score 2):

*Update.*  I was distracted by the incomplete code before but I believe I see the problem now.

Simply put `h` in `MeshFunctions` is not the `h` in your plotting function.  Note the syntax highlighting that (when correct) exists to indicate this, present also in this simpler example:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u], Sin[u] + Cos[v], Sin[v]}, {u, 0, 2 π}, {v, -π, π}, 
 MeshFunctions -> (v + #2 &)]
```

[image]

The `v` in `(v + #2 &)` is colored dark blue indicating an undefined Symbol rather than teal indicating a localized (plot) Symbol (as in `{v, -π, π}`).  This means that you cannot address the plot variable `v` by name from the `MeshFunctions` function.  The message that it generates is bogus and misleading as it of course *is* a pure function; rather I think that it should issue a message that the function did not evaluate to a meaningful specification.

From the [`MeshFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html) documentation we learn that there is another way to access these values:

> The arguments supplied to the ... MeshFunctions ... are as follows:
>
> ParametricPlot               x, y, u or x, y, u, v

This means that you can use the appropriate [`Slot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html) to access the plot variable that you want, e.g.:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u], Sin[u] + Cos[v], Sin[v]}, {u, 0, 2 π}, {v, -π, π}, 
 MeshFunctions -> (#4 + #2 &)]
```

[image]

There still remains the problem that your replacement:

```
T /. h -> #2
```

is not meaningful as there is no `h` in the definition of `T` and `β` is undefined.

---

I do not follow what you are attempting to do here but I see a couple of problems:

- Symbols `M`, `b` and `B` are never defined in your code.
- User Symbols generally should not start with capital letters to avoid conflicts with System Symbols, now or in the future.

If I define empty sets for the replacement Symbols the plot evaluates without error:

```
M = {};
b = {};
T = Cos[h];
B = T /. b;
pp[x_, y_, z_] := 
 ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, z} /. b /. M -> If[h < 0, -1, 1]*m, {m, 0, 1}, {h, -2^2, 2^2}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, MeshFunctions -> (B /. h -> #2 &)]

pp[h, m, 0]
```

[image]

Please provide a complete, working example that exhibits the error you describe.

Comment: @MrWizard thanks for all your help. What I really want is to have `T` as the mesh. I originally had `MeshFunctions -> (T /. b /. h -> #2 &)` [I must have accidentally deleted the `/.b` at some point], but that gives the same type of error even though the RHS of `b` contains an `h`.